# Show results while script is still executing

Tags: php

Right now in order to see the results, I have to wait until the entire code is done executing. It hangs until it's complete and stays loading. Once it's finished it shows all the information I was looking for.. Is there anyway to show this while the script is still running? So say if I have a print somewhere at the top of my code, I want it to show when it's called not when the script is done executing.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about ajax or php

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) like this:

```
ob_start();

echo('doing something...');

// send to browser
ob_flush();

// ... do long running stuff
echo('still going...');

ob_flush();

echo('done.');
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: It worked for me after I added `ob_implicit_flush(true)` before `ob_start()`;

Comment: I had to add ob_implicit_flush(true) and also set output_buffering = Off in php.ini

Comment: **ADD `flush();`** in some webservers the `ob_flush()` does not means that it will output the buffer to apache. [flush](http://php.net/flush)

Comment: Some browser only output if the filesize is larger then 1KB. This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192086/2311074

Comment: Had to use the ob_end_flush() to get smaller batches to echo and then start the buffer again.

Comment: This worked great for running from CLI but for running in a browser, [@Adam's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192086/3291390) lead to the solution.

Answer (score 12):

This one worked for me: ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#90529))

```
function output($str) {
    echo $str;
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    ob_start();
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is the working answer for Chrome browser, Mac OS.

Comment: thanks, it's worked for me too in Chrome.. I'm also add ob_implicit_flush(true) to the first line.

Comment: Excellent answer which works in 2021 unlike some of the others :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with output buffering. Turn on output buffering at the top of your script with `ob_start()`. That makes PHP to send no output to the browser. Instead its stored internally.
Flush your output at any time with `ob_flush()`, and the content will be sent to the browser.
But keep in mind that output buffering is influenced by many other factors. I think some versions of IIS will wait until the script is finished, ignoring output buffering. And some Antivirus software on client side (Was it *Panda*?) might wait until the page is fully loaded before passing it through to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I had to put both [`ob-flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) and [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) as shown in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109314):

```
for($i=10; $i > 0; $i--)
{
    echo "$i ...";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```