# PHP | MySQLi : How to echo statement while WHILE-LOOP is running

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

Maybe a stupid question,

I have a script that cycles through 1000s of rows in a WHILE loop.  In each pass there is an MySQLi update query being triggered, so the script takes a long time to run (10+ mins).  (this is on localhost)

In the loop I have an ECHO but the values don't show up until after the entire script is done running. I need the echos to print on the screen while its running.

Is there a way to force it to echo a value on each pass? and not do it all at the end.

Comment: Learn about PHP buffers and flushing the buffer - this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191385/php-buffer-ob-flush-vs-flush

Comment: i've tried searching for it, but had no luck.  OB_START seems to be the right thing.  Thank you.   I've tried it but doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: So I put ob_start() before WHILE-LOOP. Inside the loop i have an ECHO and after echo i have ob_clean() (tried ob_flush too).  Anyway. not working, but i least i know what to research now.   I will keep trying.  THANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415665/show-results-while-script-is-still-executing)

You can use output buffering like this:

```
ob_start();

echo('doing something...');

// send to browser
ob_flush();

// ... do long running stuff
echo('still going...');

ob_flush();

echo('done.');
ob_end_flush();
```