# php script with cron-like feature on Wamp windows

Tags: php, windows, cron, localhost, wampserver

I need run script from Windows WAMP server. It should work like this:

```
<?php
while(1){
    echo 'Start<br>';
    //Some magic here to wait 5 seconds
    echo 'End<br>';
}
?>
```

What I want is automatic work: print out `Start` -> wait 5 seconds -> print out `End` -> print out `Start` -> wait 5 seconds -> ....

In php, `Sleep(5);` is not an option because (as far as I can tell) it will wait for end of program and after that it will output `Start` and `End`. 
I cannot use `Windows Task Scheduler`, because in future, script will run at linux server. But I cannot work with cron because I am on  windows. So, basically I need something like cron, but in php on windows and wamp localhost.

So, my question is: Is there any option in php/javascript/whatever how to iterate one script 'live' with pause?

---

PYTHON EXAMPLE:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print('Start')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('End')
```

Thank you for every advice!

Comment: CRON is the linux equivilent of "Windows Task Scheduler". So while in windows, use Windows Task Scheduler, when move to linux, setup a CRON http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: it as answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445222/php-output-with-sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues you should just use [windows task scheduler](http://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/), but if you really need a `php` script,  you can use something like:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); // no time limit to execute the script
ignore_user_abort(true); //ignore if the user closes the browser or shell session
while(1){
    echo 'Start<br>';
    sleep(5);
    echo 'End<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Pedro mentioned you need a decent task schedular, you can also have a look @ [this article](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/running-php-scripts-as-cron-jobs-on-windows) to get the cron kind of functionality in windows

Comment: Task Scheduler is at least as useful as Cron